# Can a class take a different class's spell in their ritual book?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, rituals

If I am a warlock and I take the Ritual Caster feat, can I take spells from a different class and put it into my ritual casting book?

The feat says:

> When you choose this feat, you acquire a ritual book
>   holding two 1st-level spells of your choice. Choose one
>   of the following classes: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer,
>   warlock, or wizard. You must choose your spells
>   from that class’s spell list, and the spells you choose
>   must have the ritual tag. The class you choose also
>   determines your spellcasting ability for these spells:
>   Charisma for bard, sorcerer, or warlock; Wisdom for
>   cleric or druid; or Intelligence for wizard."

So, as a warlock, can the two I select be from that of a sorcerer?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 16):

## Absolutely!

As you've quoted, the [Ritual Caster feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/ritual-caster) (PHB, p. 169) is independent of your actual class. You can be a warlock and take the feat for Sorcerer rituals.

The only prerequisite is:

> Intelligence or Wisdom of 13 or higher

As long as you've got either a WIS of 13 or an INT of 13, then you can select from any of the available classes.

Comment: TL:DR: Think of this feat as an alternative to multiclassing, with the opportunity cost being a feat/ASI instead of a class level.